# Linking a photograph to my Google Sheets or a link to my Google Drive

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, links, images

I am building a catalog of products for our business, I would like to have an option where as you roll over the item a photo of the product will appear, in the same way 'add note' works but with a picture instead of just writing.

I understand how to add links to websites of similar things, but none of which are quite right or what I want. I also know how to add a photo, but I don't want them on all the time, just when you scroll past it or click on it.

I can add a link from my Google Drive but it results in having to click on it and opening another webpage, I was hoping to just have it as a pop up but if that's all I can do I will have to live with it.

I think maybe its a really simple solution that I am just either missing or haven't worked out yet but any pointers would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Around the time of asking, and still as far as I am aware, "not possible":

> Like a "comment" or a "note" when you hover over the cell that has either one a small window will pop-up showing the "comment" or the "note". You want to insert an image so that when you hover over the cell a small window showing the image will pop-up. Is that correct?
>
> If so then that feature is currently not available in Google Sheets.

[James/mreighties](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/uAZ4qFFmY2s) 21/05/2015